# Differential of the Rabinowitz Action Functional

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, floer-homology

On an exact Hamiltonian system $(M,d\alpha,H)$ define the **Rabinowitz action functional** 
$$\mathcal{A}^H \colon C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^1,M) \times (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$$
by
$$\mathcal{A}^H(\gamma,\tau) := \int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\gamma^*\alpha - \int_{\mathbb{S}^1}H(\gamma(t))dt.$$
Following the book *The Restricted Three-Body Problem and Holomorphic Curves* by *Frauenfelder/Koert*, p. 97 it is claimed that
$$d\mathcal{A}^H_{(\gamma,\tau)}(X,\widehat{\tau}) = \int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\gamma^*\mathcal{L}_X\alpha - \tau \int_{\mathbb{S}^1}dH(X) - \widehat{\tau}\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}H \circ \gamma$$ 
for any pair
$$(X,\widehat{\tau}) \in T_\gamma C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^1,M) \times \mathbb{R} = \Gamma(\gamma^*TM) \times \mathbb{R}.$$
I do not understand this computation. I mean, it is clear to me that to compute the differential (or merely define it in that infinite-dimensional setting), we pick a variation of $(\gamma,\tau)$, for example
$$\Gamma(\varepsilon,t) := (\exp_{\gamma(t)}^\nabla(\varepsilon X_t), \tau + \varepsilon \widehat{\tau}).$$
Then 
$$d\mathcal{A}^H_{(\gamma,\tau)}(X,\widehat{\tau}) = \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg\vert_{\varepsilon = 0}\mathcal{A}^H(\Gamma(\varepsilon,\cdot)).$$ So in the first term we end up with 
$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg\vert_{\varepsilon = 0}\gamma_\varepsilon^*\alpha,$$ where $\gamma_\varepsilon := \exp_\gamma^\nabla(\varepsilon X)$. **What I do not understand is, why that**
$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg\vert_{\varepsilon = 0}\gamma_\varepsilon^*\alpha = \int_{\mathbb{S}^1}\gamma^*\mathcal{L}_X\alpha.$$ I mean, since $X$ is only a vector field along $\gamma$, for me, the expression $\mathcal{
L}_X\alpha$ does not even make sense.

Comment: The identity $\frac{d}{d \varepsilon}\gamma^*_\varepsilon \alpha =\gamma^* \mathcal{L}_X \alpha$ is the definition of the right hand side, similarly to how you define the ordinary Lie derivative in terms of the flow. I would denote it by$\mathcal{L}^\gamma_X \alpha$ to emphasize that it's the Lie derivative along $\gamma$. One should note that $\mathcal{L}_X \alpha$ in itself does not make sense, and, in particular does not yield a differential form on $M$ (it's however a "differential form along $\gamma$" in the sense that its pullback by $\gamma$ gives a differential form on $\mathbb{S}^1$).

Comment: @TobiasDiez Thank you. However, after that they use *Cartan's Magic Formula* $$\mathcal{L}_X\alpha = i_Xd\alpha + di_X\alpha$$ to proceed. My idea was to do not introduce the Lie derivative notation and to prove directly that $$\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg\vert_{\varepsilon = 0}\gamma_\varepsilon^*\alpha = \gamma^*(i_Xd\alpha + di_X\alpha),$$ but I guess one has to do this in coordinates.

Comment: Yes, a form of the Cartan formula holds (but with $d \gamma^* i_X \alpha$ in the second term because $i_X \alpha$ is again not a differential form on $M$). You can prove this formula by noticing that it is sufficient to check it for functions and $1$-forms because these generate the whole algebra of differential forms.

Comment: @TobiasDiez Thank you! I find it a bit strange that it is written that way in the book.